# jqGrid record text alignment

Tags: jquery, text, jqgrid, alignment

Im pretty new to jqGrid and Im having a problem displaying the recordtext in the pager. Here is the picture:

[image: The recordtext is not being fully displayed]

As you can see the recordtext is not being fully displayed. I set the text to the right but I dont want it to be truncated. Here is the code:

```
gridMed.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            loadonce: true,
            colModel: gridMedColModel,
            height: '230',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            headertitles: false,
            pager: $('#pagerMedico'),
            recordtext: "Mostrando {0} - {1} de " + cantidadRegistros + mensaje,
            pgtext: null,
            pgbuttons: false,
            rowList: [],
            shrinkToFit: false
        }).navGrid('#pagerMedico', { edit: false, add: true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this:

```
loadComplete: function(){
    $('#pager2_left').css('width', 70); // this will make more space for text.
}
```

---

Here `#pager2_left` is the navGrid pagers parent `td`'s id and the width is divided to them equally, so you have to give a lower width to the `#pager2_left` td, it will shrink little bit and more space will be available for the other one.